# Create Microsoft graph subscription for all users of a tenant

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, change-notification

I have created an application (with application level permissions) which creates subscription for receiving notifications when an user receives an email. Currently, I have to create multiple subscriptions for multiple users of an tenant.

Is there a way I can create a single subscription for all users of a tenant and receive notification whenever any user in the tenant receives a mail?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry , single subscription is not supported for multiple user, you need to use individual user in the tenant.
[image]

Please check out the docs for more info regarding subscription - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0 and to setup notification, please follow docs- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks